# How to make Aptana's keyboard shortcuts to be layout independent?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Aptana Studio 3.6.1.

When I edit source code in Aptana I want to save it on disk. While I am in English keyboard layout I can press Ctrl+S. But when I use Russian keyboard layout this shortcut does not work.

Answer (score 1):

you can get shortcut key combinations via Help > Key Assist[image]

Comment: thanks.I found that Aptana supports more then one shortcut for a command. So I copied, Save command and assigned Ctrl+Ы on it. Now I have two shortcuts on Save command and both work in corresponding keyboard layout.